# show that statements are equivalent (Sobolev Spaces)

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Given $u \in L^p(\Bbb R)$, $1<p<\infty$, show that the following statements are equivalent:

1. $u\in W^{1,p}(\Bbb R)$
2. $\exists c>0 $ such that for $\forall h \in R$ the following inequality takes place:
   $$
   \|u(x+h)-u(x-h)\|_{L^p(\Bbb R)}\le c|h|
   $$

======================================================

Can you tell me if this is right, please?

1. $\forall x,h \in\Bbb R$:
   $$
   u(x+h)-u(x-h)=\int_{x-h}^{x+h}u'(t)dt
   $$
   By the change of variable: $t=sh+x-h$ ($dt = hds$ i.e. $s=\left(\frac{t-x+h}{h}\right)$, for $t=x-h: s=0$, for ,$t=x+h$, $s=2$) we have:
   $$
   \begin{split}
   u(x+h)-u(x-h) & = h\int_o^2 u'(x+sh-h) ds\\
   \implies |u(x+h)-u(x-h)| &\le |h|\int_0^2|u'(x+sh-h)|ds
   \end{split}
   $$
   From Holder's Inequality:
   $$
   \begin{split}
   |u(x+h)-u(x-h)|^p &\le|h|^p\int_0^2|u'(x+sh-h)|^pds \\
   &\Downarrow\\
   \int_R|u(x+h)-u(x-h)|^pdx & \le|h|^p\int_Rdx\int_0^2|u'(x+sh-h)|^pds\\
   & \le|h|^p\int_0^2ds\int_R|u'(x+sh-h)|^pdx \\
   & =2|h|^p\int_R|u'(x+sh-h)|^pdx\\
   &\Downarrow \\
   \int_R|u'(x+sh-h)|^pdx & =\int_R|u'(y)|^pdy \,\,s\in(0,1)
   \end{split}
   $$
2. Getting $z\in C_c^1, \forall h \in \Bbb R:$
   $$
   \int_R(u(x+h)-u(x-h))z(x)dx=\int_Ru(x)(z(x-h)-z(x+h))dx
   $$
   By applying Holder's inequality:
   $$
   \left|\int_R(u(x+h)-u(x-h))dx\right|\le c|h|\,\|z\|_{L^{p'}(\Bbb R)}
   $$
   and multiplying with $1/h$ and letting $h\to 0$:
   $$
   \left| \int_R uz^{\prime}\right| \le c\|z\|_{L^{p'}(\Bbb R)}
    \implies u \in W^{1,p}
   $$

Comment: Do you have any thoughts? People are more likely to help if you show some sign of having attempted the problem yourself.

Comment: I've done it :)