# Lipschitz continuity of translation in $L^p$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R})$ for $1\leq p <\infty,$ then $||f(x+h)-f(x)||_{L^p(\mathbb{R})} \rightarrow 0$ as $h\rightarrow 0$.

Furthermore, for $p=1,$ if $u\in L^1(\mathbb{R}) \cap W^{1,1}(\mathbb{R})$ then in fact we have $$||f(x+h)-f(x)||_{L^1(\mathbb{R})} \leq C h,$$ where $C$ depends on $f$ and independent of $h.$

Do we have such estimates for $p>1$?

i.e. $u\in L^p(\mathbb{R}) \cap W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R})$ do we have

$$||f(x+h)-f(x)||_{L^p(\mathbb{R})} \leq C h^k,$$
$k$ may depend on $p.$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1733355

Comment: $f(x+h) - f(x) = \int^{x+h}_x f'(s)~\mathrm{d}s$ for a.e. x, h. Then apply the $L^p$-norm of your choice on both sides and use Hölder.